# Reloading D3 Graph With Same Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After staring at my screen for several days in a row trying to find a solution to this, I couldn't find one. Everything I've seen shows graphs being reloaded with new data, not the same data. If I want to keep the same data and same everything but still reload the graph, how would I do so. This [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HfnIs1PlYcXCTcdHTLHA?p=preview) should give an idea of where I want it implemented. I have almost everything done, I just need to know a way to straight up reload only the graphs. Thanks.

The reload would go in here (yes, I do have another piece of JavaScript that allows onresize of divs).

```
function finalResize(){
}
addResizeListener(frontElement, finalResize);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to "reload" the graph? Is it so that the size of the graph will adjust when the window is resized?

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin you should be able to change the range and scale again to adjust the graph to the window size.  You don't need to reload the data if it hasn't changed.